# If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$, establish an inequality involving the Fourier transform.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Assume $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$. I would like to show that

$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{2}|f(x)|^{2} d x\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \xi^{2}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2} d \xi\right) \geq \frac{1}{16 \pi^{2}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^{2} d x\right)^{2}
$$
where $\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx$ is the Fourier transform.

Analysis is definitely not my strong suit so here goes, and Fourier analysis is still new to me. Also, I perused the questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525348/inequality-for-fourier-transform) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489133/an-inequality-involving-the-l1-norm-and-a-fourier-transform) to see what techniques are used.

The right hand side looks like an inner product of $f(x)/4\pi$ with itself in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and then squared. Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality does not look reasonable in this case. At the very least, I can take the square root of both sides, I can rewrite this as
$$
\left \langle \frac{f(x)}{4\pi},\frac{f(x)}{4\pi} \right \rangle\leq \|xf(x)\|_2\|\xi\hat{f}(\xi)\|_2.
$$
Naively applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I get
$$
\left \langle \frac{f(x)}{4\pi},\frac{f(x)}{4\pi} \right \rangle\leq \|f(x)/4\pi\|_2\|f(x)/4\pi\|_2.
$$
I suspect I need to use Fourier inversion in some nontrivial manner. In this case, $f^2\in L^1$ so Fourier inversion says that $\hat{f^2}^\vee=f^2$ where the $\vee$ indicates the Fourier transform inverse given by $g^\vee=\hat{g}(-x)$. Then, I could appeal to the Hausdorff-Young inequality. My only issue here though is that I have no clue where the $x^2,\xi^2$ terms are coming from. Actually, I'm not even sure how I can cancel out the $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ terms from the upper bound I get.

A hint is preferred, but a general suggestion on how to approach similar problems is even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $\int_\mathbb{R} \vert x \vert^2 \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx =\infty$, then the inequality is trivial. Thus, we assume for the rest $\int_\mathbb{R} \vert x \vert^2 \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx <\infty$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus we get

$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \vert f (x) \vert^2 dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{f}(x) x \frac{1}{x} \left( f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x f'(y) dy \right)dx. $$

First we consider the second term. We have

$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{f}(x) x \frac{1}{x}  \int_{x_0}^x f'(y) dy dx
\leq \left( \int_\mathbb{R} x^2 \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx\right)^{1/2}\left( \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\vert x \vert} \int_{x_0}^x \vert f'(y) \vert^2  \right)^{1/2}
\leq \left( \int_\mathbb{R} x^2 \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx\right)^{1/2}\left( 4\int_\mathbb{R} \vert f'(x) \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2}, $$
where we used Hardy's inequality to pass to the last line.

For the second term we note that we just need to show that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then we just choose $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ gets smaller and smaller to eliminate this term. For this we use Cauchy-Schwarz and that $f$ is locally bounded
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \vert f(x) \vert dx = \int_{[-1, 1]} \vert f(x) \vert dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert x \vert \vert f(x) \vert \frac{1}{x} dx
\leq 2 \sup_{x\in [-1,1]} \vert f(x) \vert + \left( \int_\mathbb{R} x^2 \vert f(x) \vert^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( 2 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx \right)^{1/2} <\infty. $$

Hence, we have shown so far

$$ \left( \int_\mathbb{R} \vert f (x) \vert^2 dx \right)^2 
\leq 4 \left( \int_\mathbb{R} x^2 \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx\right)\left( \int_\mathbb{R} \vert f'(x) \vert^2 dx \right). $$

Finally we note that by Parseval's identity we have

$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \vert f'(x) \vert^2 dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert \widehat{f'}(\xi) \vert^2 d\xi. $$

Now use that $\widehat{f'}(\xi)= 2\pi i \xi \widehat{f}(\xi)$ to conclude.

Comment: This looks good from what I can tell. I'm not picking up on how I might approach similar problems. Could you provide some indication on how to arrive at such a proof? Your comments already did part of that job. I'll accept the answer since it gives a complete proof.

Comment: I must admit that I cannot tell you how to approach a similar problem. I tried just a bunch of things and arrived at this solution.

Comment: Essentially I wanted to use Cauchy-Schwarz, however, then you have to deal with $f(x)/x$. In dimension $d\geq 3$ one could directly use Hardy's inequality $$\Vert f/\vert .\vert \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq C_p \Vert \nabla f \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$ Unfortunately it does not hold directly for $d=1$. So I looked at Hardy's inequality for $d=1$ and noted that I need to make the derivative appear, so I used the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @xkxdxtxdx One other way to establish the crucial inequality is to assume $xf(\cdot)$ and $f'$ are in $L^2$ (otherwise the inequality is trivially true). Now, integrate by parts to get $\int_a^b|f(x)|^2\,dx=[x|f(x)|^2]_a^b-2\int_a^b\text{Re}(x\overline{f(x)}f'(x))\,dx$. Try to justify why (using the assumption $xf(\cdot),f'\in L^2$) as $a\to -\infty$ and $b\to \infty$, the boundary term drops out and we get $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|f(x)|^2=-2\int_{\Bbb{R}}\text{Re}(x\overline{f(x)}\cdot f'(x))\,dx$. Now, use Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: You asked where the $x^2$ and $\xi^2$ terms come up from. Well, in this derivation, an $x$ term comes up from integrating by parts (similar to how $\int\log x=x\log x -\int x\log'(x)\,dx$). This then becomes $x^2$ due to Cauchy-Schwarz. Finally, as explained in this answer, because of the appearance of $f'(x)$, we can use Plancharel's identity to involve $\widehat{f'}(\xi)=2\pi i \xi\widehat{f}(\xi)$. So, finally the $16\pi^2$ constant comes up because of $|2|^2|2\pi i|^2$.

Comment: @xkxdxtxdx In fact I started by noting that $\vert \xi \vert \vert \widehat{f}\vert$ relates to $\vert \widehat{f'}(\xi)\vert$. This is because it looks like an "uncertainty principle" (one cannot be both localised in space and momentum, like one gets from the Heisenberg uncertainty principle).

Comment: I appreciate the details from @SeverinSchraven and peek-a-boo
I will be reading through the comments at a later time and ask more questions if any come up. Thank you for helping an "algebraic" person like me out with some of the suggestions and thought process!